# Cheerio returns undefined when I try to retrieve JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, cheerio

I am trying to make a webscraber, and have succeded in downloading the html. With this code I now try to find the title of my html:

```
fs.readFile(__filename.json , function (err, data) {
if(err) throw err;

const $ = cheerio.load(data);
const urlElemt = $('article.product-tile');

if(urlElemt){
    console.log("Found " + urlElemt.length + " elements");

    let urlTitle = $(urlElemt.find("h2.product-tile__title"));
    let urlPrice = $(urlElemt.find("span.__price"));

    for(let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        console.log(Title[i].children)
    }
}
```

When I just console.log the children of the object I get:

```
[ { type: 'text',
data: 'Tuborg Grøn Pilsner Øl 4,6%',
parent: 
 { type: 'tag',
   name: 'h2',
   namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
   attribs: [Object],
   'x-attribsNamespace': [Object],
   'x-attribsPrefix': [Object],
   children: [Circular],
   parent: [Object],
   prev: [Object],
   next: [Object] },
prev: null,
next: null } ]
```

where data: 'Tuborg Grøn Pilsner Øl 4,6%',
is the data I want to retrieve.

I have tried using both

```
console.log(Title[i].children["data"])
```

and

```
console.log(Title[i].children.data)
```

but I always get "undefined" as a result, what have I misunderstood and/or been doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
const urlElemt = $('article.product-tile')
...
let urlTitle = $(urlElemt.find("h2.product-tile__title"))
```

`find()` function already returns a Cheerio object, hence you don't need to pass it to `$` function. This will suffice:

```
let urlTitle = urlElemt.find("h2.product-tile__title")
```

thus you can do

```
console.log(urlTitle.text())
```

or

```
console.log(urlTitle.html())
```

to see the serialized versions of the dom nodes, which in your case should be a plain text string. (see [the api docs](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/tree/426b555173fbb6ac4718a38c23e261ce0235ca6a#html-htmlstring-))